# How to static_assert the size of a std::array member

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, static-assert, stdarray

I would like to be explicit about array size restrictions on a member variable, to stop others from accidentally making silly changes.  The following naive attempt will not compile:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::array< int, 1024 > some_array;
    static_assert( (some_array.size() % 256) == 0, "Size must be multiple of 256" );
    //^ (clang) error: invalid use of non-static data member 'some_array'
};
```

Even though `std::array::size` is a *constexpr*, I can't directly use `static_assert` like that because neither the function nor my member variable is static.

The solution I came up with is to use `decltype` (since I don't want to typedef the array) as follows:

```
static_assert( (decltype(some_array)().size() % 256) == 0, "Size must be multiple of 256" );
```

This looks like it's default-constructing an *rvalue*, which I didn't think is a *constexpr*.

Why does this work?

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the static assertion?

Comment: Your function works fine for me sir o.o, in vusal studio.

Comment: `(declval<decltype(some_array)>().size() % 256) == 0` doesn't work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> because neither the function nor my member variable is static.

Right. The problem is that the static assert can't refer to a non-static member, because `some_array.size()` is equivalent to `this->some_array.size()` and there is no `this` pointer at class scope (only inside function declarators and default member initializers).

However, it is OK to say `decltype(array_size)` because that isn't actually trying to refer to the object `array_size` or invoke its member functions, it's just querying the type of a name declared in the class.

> This looks like it's default-constructing an rvalue, which I didn't think is a constexpr.

`array<int, N>` is a literal type, so can be constructed in constant expressions. The fact you're constructing an rvalue doesn't matter, you can construct a literal type and call a constexpr member function on it in a constant expression.

Something like `array<std::string, N>` could not be used there, because `std::string` is not a literal type, and so neither is `array<string, N>`.

> Is there a cleaner way to achieve the static assertion?

The standard trait `std::tuple_size` is specialized for `std::array` so you can do:

```
static_assert( std::tuple_size<decltype(some_array)>::value % 256) == 0,
               "Size must be multiple of 256" );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem when you inherit from `std::array` and want to use structure bindings for the derived class. In this case, you need to define a partial template specialization of and can thus not rely on `std::tuple_size` for your derived class.

Answer (score 9):

`std::array::size` is `constexpr` and should work with `static_assert`, however it doesn't work in this particular context (i.e., in class definition) because `some_array` is a non-static member variable.

For this particular context you could use a home made type trait to take the size at compile time like below:

```
template<typename>
struct array_size;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array_size<std::array<T, N>> {
  static const std::size_t size = N;
};
```

And `static_assert` as:

```
static_assert(array_size<decltype(some_array)>::size % 256) == 0, "Size must be multiple of 256" );
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d262824cc7c5fd2e)

Comment: Looks like you mixed up type and value metafunctions :)

Comment: This is kind of how I expected `std::array` would be implemented...  Why not have direct access to the template's size value?  But that's not the case.  While this is a cool solution, I'm not sure if it's really "cleaner", as it seems to require even more framework.

Comment: `using size = N;` is not valid, that would declare a typedef, but `N` is not a type. You probably want `template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array_size<std::array<T, N>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> { };` which would then define `array_size<A>::value` to be the size. However, that already exists in the standard library, `std::tuple_size` works with `std::array`

Comment: @paddy, the array size is a member function, not a static constant, for consistency with the other containers. Generic code that works with STL-style containers can rely on`begin()`, `end()`, `size()` etc.